# PyQt5: QFileDialog triggered as many times as plugin is opened

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I am new to QGIS and I'm building a plugin on it. The problem I'm facing, I believe, concerns mostly PyQt5.

So, in my plugin I'm trying to open a file through `getOpenFileName()` of `QFileDialog`. I noticed that the dialog for opening the file is triggered as many times I trigger the plugin without reloading (using Plugin Reloader). Putting it simply, the dialog for opening the file pops up as many times in a row as I test the plugin without reloading it. The first time user has to input file name once, the second time twice, third time thrice and so on. I want this dialog to pop up just once and get the input from the user.

I'm using Plugin Builder. Here's my code for reference:

```
def loadData(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop

    self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
    self.dlg.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)

    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # ...

def select_output_file(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.dlg, "Select file", "")[0]
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(self.tr(filename))
```

Here, `lineEdit` is the name for text field where the path of the file being opened appears, `toolButton` is the button that is clicked to trigger this action and `dlg` is the instance for main dialog box of the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely because each time the plugin is run, you are adding another `connect` signal to the function. You should `disconnect` this at the end of your `loadDate(self)` function using:

```
self.dlg.toolButton.clicked.disconnect(self.select_output_file)
```